# Java Enum private method in item's constructor

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

```
public enum Parent {
    item1(1){

        public void testing() {
            add();
            multiply();
            minus(); // error here!!!
        } 

    }, item2(2);

    private int i ;
    Parent(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void setI(int i ){
        this.i = i;
    }
    public int getI(){
        return i;
    }

    public void multiply(){

    }
    protected void add(){

    }

    private void minus(){

    }
}
```

As you guy can see, they are in the same class, how come `minus()` cannot be used internally? Usually inner class can access `private method/field` in the outer class right?

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to access `minus()` from `item1`, you have to make it `protected` (or `public`).

The correct way to think about `Parent` and `item1` is as a base class and a subclass.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1):

> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) **that extends the immediately enclosing enum type**.

Answer (score 3):

Actually what happens is when you provide implementation while creating enum object, you are basically extending the `Parent` class with an extra method i.e. **Annonymous** implementation. So it does not allow to access private method of `Parent` class but allows `protected` and `public`.

```
enum A{
        a{
            @Override
            public void method() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.method();
            }
        };


        public void method(){

        }
    }
```

This should explain see the `@Override` annotation provided by eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "item1" is not an inner class of Parent, it's in fact top level class. To verify see generated class for item1, it is Parent$1.class, if it was an inner class it would be Parent$item1.class